# Clang compiles code in GCC define block

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, warnings, pragma

I have the following code:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmaybe-uninitialized"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-but-set-variable"
#endif
```

However if I compile my code with Clang, I get the error `error: unknown warning group`. Why does clang compile the code after the `#ifdef __GNUC__`?

Comment: Possible alternative [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1617877/1708801)

Comment: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/10/c_c_tip_how_detect_compiler_name_and_version_using_compiler_predefined_macros The chart on this page says that Intel has the same dishonest habit. How disappointing.